# Prevent calling parent when nested ui-sref

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let say I have nested DOMs and each has `ui-sref` for different `angular-ui-router` state. I want to click **outer** to only alert outer and click **inner** to only alert inner. Currently if I click **inner**, it will alert both outer and inner state.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.13"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@0.2.8" data-semver="0.2.8" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a ui-sref="outer" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:yellow;">
      Outer
            <span ui-sref="inner" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red;">Inner</span>
    </a>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

'use strict';

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state("outer", {
      url: "/outer",
      resolve: {
        test: function() {
          alert("Triggered state outer");
          return true;
        }
      }
    })
    .state("inner", {
      url: "/inner",
      resolve: {
        test: function() {
          alert("Triggered state inner");
          return true;
        }
      }
    });

}]);


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/yzgUAA3lLwkF9svzczl3?p=preview

**Questions**:

1. How to prevent inner to trigger outer state?
2. Should I implement some kind of `stopImmediatePropagation` for the inner DOM so it won't trigger the parent DOM's `ui-sref`?
3. Are there alternatives? Maybe using `$state.go` manually?

**UPDATE 1:**

I cannot change HTML due to requirement. This is just a simplified version because in my code, the outer element is very large containing other elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works

```
<a ui-sref="outer" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:yellow;">
  Outer
        <span ui-sref="inner" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red;" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">Inner</span>
</a>
```

I didn't know you can add `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"` in the same element as `ui-sref`

Comment: It works but I appear to be getting a whole page reload which is probably not the desired behaviour ... certainly not for me.

Comment: ui-sref updates the href item of the a tag, it has no effect on the click event. Just as with jQuery you can ```$('a').attr('href', 'http://example.com').on('click', (e) => {/*something*/})```

Answer (score 40):

USE THIS...

```
 <a ui-sref="outer" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:yellow;">
 Outer
     <span ui-sref="inner" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red;"
     ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">Inner</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Your kung-fu is strong David.

Comment: I had a similar case, but instead of inner link I had to call a function. Using only $event.stopPropagation() still caused a navigation. Adding $event.preventDefault() fixed the issue. I got inspiration from http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636705/2487876

Comment: Very strong indeed. Kudos to you!

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution. It is great for prototyping and simple items. it would be best to have a specialized attribute like the ```stopEvent``` above

Comment: You are strong in the ways of the Force, David.

Answer (score 2):

For a completely different purpose I had a stopEvent directive just waiting to be used for the nested `ui-sref` purpose.

```
<a ui-sref="outer">
  Outer
  <span ui-sref="inner" stop-event>Inner</span>
</a>
```

This is the directive

```
app.directive('stopEvent', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      element.bind('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your javascript code but your html

```
  <a ui-sref="outer" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:yellow;">
      Outer
            <span ui-sref="inner" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red;">Inner</span>
    </a>
```

when you click anywhere inside the  tag, outer state will be invoked.

your

Inner

lies inside  tag so this html element is bound to both ui-sref="inner" and ui-sref="outer"

the below code should solve your problem

```
<a ui-sref="outer" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:yellow;">
      Outer

    </a>

<span ui-sref="inner" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red;">Inner</span>
```

Comment: Please see my `update 1`. I am aware of changing HTML to fix this but it's not my scope.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I implement some kind of `stopImmediatePropagation` for the inner DOM so it won't trigger the parent DOM's `ui-sref`?

Yes, exactly.

Alternately, you might be able to rearrange your HTML so that the don't have a parent/child relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Add the event stop propogation/event prevent default  at ur inner stateprovider :

```
  $stateProvider.state("outer", {
      url: "/outer",
      resolve: {
       test: function() {
      alert("Triggered state outer");
      return true;
    }
  }
}).state("inner", {
     url: "/inner",
     resolve: {
     test: function() {

      alert("Triggered state inner");
      //$event.stopPropagation();
      $event.preventDefault();
      return true;
    }
  }
})
```

**Update 1:** I tried on plunker demo and $event is available. As per angular doc also for
 Event object is available as $event. [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wqgXQSfrKe4wkk8zcSHB?p=preview) [Angular doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

**Update 2:** Above works if u press outer div first  but that's not rt solution I agree. So here is another solution which works. checking the statechangestart of scope and saving last state name in var and checking if its inner then event preventdefault;

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.name = 'World';
   var laststate = "";
   $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
     function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
               //alert(laststate);
      if (laststate == "inner") {
         event.preventDefault();
       }
      laststate = toState.name;
    });
  });
```

[**DEMO Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/r4yifomHNzPTdix9CoUw?p=preview)

Comment: I clicked Inner and it alerted both Inner a and outer, therefore not meeting requirement

Comment: This "hack" works but it's not ideal as I may have `inner1` to `inner1000`. So the solution must be generic enough to handle tons of different DOMs and states within other DOMs with their own states.